# Modified Record in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I was creating report we contact records which are modified or their child entity is changed in last 24 hours. I was enable to group Or in modified-on of contact and modified-on of its child entity. So created a custom field "activity modified-on" on contact and run a workflow on demand on child entity which set "activity modified-on" to its modified-on.

But actual contact modified-on also changed.

Now, I want that actual contact modified-on to its original date/value.

can I use audit or other things.

Comment: can you please explain better your requirement?

Comment: Hi, Preite I changed my question witch detail now, please take a look.